# Using CAST with SUBSTR to limit decial places

Tags: sql

I am using the string below to convert the stored length in inches to feet, but I'm getting 15 decimal places in the process.  I'm not sure if CAST will work with this string or not, but either way, I can't figure it out.  Help?

```
SUBSTR(LL_WW_HH_INCHES,1,3)/12 AS "LENGTH IN FT"
```

FYI:  LL_WW_HH_INCHES returns 9 digits that look something like this 123456789.  I only need the first three digits and want to divide that by 12.

Comment: You're casting a numeric value into a string, and then dividing that by a numeric value...  Why not just divide it first, then format it?

Comment: @Siyual has an angle. Why not get the correct value first, then try to format it later?

Comment: I can't divide it first because I need to isolate the first three digits in a 9 digit result.  Does that make sense, or am I not understanding your statement?

Comment: I provided more info in my post

Comment: I ended up figuring out and simplifying my results in the process.  I used    DECIMAL(ROUND(SUBSTR(LL_WW_HH_INCHES,1,3)/12,2),2) AS "LENGTH IN FT"

Comment: are you using db2 or is it a general sql question?

Comment: @Robblob If you've solved the problem please post an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted; this prevents other readers attempting to answer a solved question.